# Determine $\frac{|PB|}{|AB|}$ if S=S'

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be an equilateral triangle and P a point of [AB], closer to B than to A. Let Q be the point of [BC] such that PQ is perpendicular to AB, R the point of [AC] such that QR is perpendicular at BC, and S the point of [AB] such that RS is perpendicular to AC. Let Q ′ be the point of [BC] such that PQ ′ is perpendicular to BC, R ′ the point of [AC] such that Q′R ′ is perpendicular to AC and S ′ the point of [AB] such that R′S ′ Is perpendicular to AB.
Determine $\frac{|PB|}{|AB|}$ if S=S'

Comment: Please use mathjax to have a proper format of the mathematical symbols in the OP. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Please ask a question - as it is, the posted text ends with an imperative. Please provide **context** to the question, e.g. what did you try, where did you get stuck, which is the source, the level, etc. ? Since this is a geometric context, a picture would be nice to have. This would share the effort, and a potential answerer may have a pointed answer. Could you please edit the posted text to better fit the site rules?!

Comment: I have the solution but I want to see what you have tried first and help you from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer :* $\frac{|PB|}{|AB|}=\frac{7}{2}$.

*Explanation :*

Let's L be the point of [RQ] such that [LS] is parallel to [AC].

L is also the point of [R'Q'] such that [LP] is parallel to [BC].

L is also the intersection of [QR] and [Q'R'].

Triangle LPS is equilateral, triangles Q'BP and RAS are similar, triangles AR'S and BQP are similar.

$|QP| = |R'S'|$; $|BP|=|AS|$; $|PS|=\frac{3}{2}|BP|$

Here is the [image: graph]

Comment: Your result is incorrect. The correct answer is $2/7$ because $PS=3/2BP$.